# Inject React component into html page

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm trying to do something with React but i don't know if i'm doing it in the right way...

i created a React component (using create-react-app).

i putted the js files (after build) on a web server.

after that, on a html page, when i click on a button, i insert the js files.
if a div with a particular id exists on the page, the component is loaded.

it was cool, i was happy for what i've done, Hurray \o/

but after that, i tried to remove the component (emptying the div) and reload clicking on a button but nothing happened...

the function called when i click on the button removes scripts, empties the div et re-inserts scripts.
But nothing happen... and i don't know why :/

any help would be greatly appreciated :D

Thx in advance

EDIT :
i solved my problem.
i was deleting the script assuming that re-injecting it would reload the component but it doesn't work like that...

here is a sample code : https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-fire-ytbj9?file=/public/index.html

i wrote a function in the React component to render it. i can call this function directly in the html page so i can empty the div and reload the component on clicking on the reload button.

Comment: Could you please share the code snippet, so we can better identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you do is not standard, you must create a container for your react component in your web app, then write your component like this:

```
const rc = React.createElement;

class ReactExample extends React.Component {    
  render() {
    return rc(
      'button',
      { onClick: () => alert("Hello from ReactJS!") },
      'say hi'
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(rc(ReactExample), document.querySelector('#reactContainer'));
```

save it in a js file, then import it into your HTML page.

NOTE: You can use JSX if you need it, but you have to transpile your JSX using by [babel](https://babeljs.io/repl#?browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwIwrgLhD2B2AEcDCAbAlgYwNYF4DeAFAJTw4B88EAFmgM4B0tAphAMoQCGETBe86WJgBMAXJQBOYJvAC-RGWQBQ8FfAAyaQYuAB6cFDhkgA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.13.9&externalPlugins=).

in the end, import `react` to the project:

***for production:***

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" crossorigin></script>
```

***for development:***

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin></script>
```